# Why does double type look different between linux and windows

Tags: linux, postgresql, window, odbc

For a little background, I am currently working on converting a solution from windows to linux. The solution is essentially using ODBC to interact with a postgreSQL database by both reading and writing as required. I am running a Debian build through Oracle VM VirtualBox.

For some (unknown to me) reason when fetching data from a query I am receiving a different double value when executing on LINUX. For example if I query the DB directly using PGadmin I'll get a value like 1.09933996200562 (type:double precision), if I run the same query from my solution with ODBC I get 1.09934 (this slight rounding off is okay for my purposes). However when running an identical query via odbc from my solution on LINUX I get back 1.10237. Note: The solution is storing the returned value as a double in both cases.

Does anyone know what is causing it to round off the value in this manner on LINUX? I've attempted storing the value as a long double to see if that could have any affect but it did not go well. If anyone has any experience with solving this issue it would be much appreciated.

As suggested here is a portion of the program which will re-create the issue...

```
void main()
{
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvH = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE sqlConnH = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE hStmt = NULL;
    string SQLConnectionString;
    char connectionString[256];
    SQLSMALLINT numCols;



    SQLConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=localhost;Port=5544;Database=TSDB4;Uid=;Pwd=;";
    strcpy(connectionString, SQLConnectionString.c_str());

    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvH))
        cout << "ok" << endl;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvH, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        cout << "ok1" << endl;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvH, &sqlConnH))
    {
        cout << "ok2" << endl;

        SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];

        SQLRETURN retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
            sqlConnH,
            NULL,
            (SQLCHAR *)  connectionString,
            SQL_NTS,
            retconstring,
            1024,
            NULL,
            SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

        if ((retcode == SQL_SUCCESS))
        {
            cout << "success" << endl;
        }
        else if(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            cout << "success with info" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "failure on connect..." <<endl;

    }

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,sqlConnH, &hStmt))
        cout << "failed to alloc stmt handle" << endl;

    SQLExecDirect(hStmt,(SQLCHAR*)"select * from usp_getseriesparameters(1)", SQL_NTS) ;


    if(SQLNumResultCols (hStmt, &numCols) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "no column numbers?" << endl;
    }

    cout << numCols << endl;

    if(SQLFetch(hStmt) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "fail \n";
    }

    double retVal[256];
    double FieldValue;

    if ( SQL_NO_DATA != SQLGetData(hStmt,5,SQL_C_DEFAULT,retVal,256,NULL))
    {
        FieldValue = *retVal;
        cout << FieldValue << endl;
    }

    SQLRETURN retcode;

}
```

Note that the EXECDirect is querying a table in the database (column 5) which contains values stored as 'double-precision'. This displays 1.09934 on windows and 1.10237 on LINUX.

Comment: Might be the different ODBC implementation. A little self-contained program that exhibits the problem would help others to find an explanation.

Comment: I have added some snippets which should be enough to recreate the issue.

Comment: I tried it with `SELECT pi()` and it works fine. If I output the value with `printf("%3.20f\n", FieldValue);`, I get 3.14159265358979311600. Perhaps you should use `setprecision` to set `cout` to a greater precision.